# How to understand index of while loop in binary search?

Tags: c, loops, binary-search

For an array `a`, if I want to get the sum of all the elements, I can use `for loop` to access all elements in array `a`. And the times of loop is the amount of element in array `a`. Each time, loop is actually access to element in array `a`.

```
int sum(int a[], int n)
{
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       sum += a[i];
   return sum;
}
```

However, when it comes to binary search, it's pretty hard to understand the loop in the same way. Please tell me is there some good way to understand loop with low and high index? I can relate the index `i` to the element of array `a` in the first example. Then how to understand the index `low` and `high`, and what can I relate them to. What is the difference between while(low <= high) and while(low < high)?

```
int binarySearch(int a[], int n, int x)
{
   int low=0, mid, high=n-1;
   while(low <= high)
   {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (x < a[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (x > a[mid])
         low = mid + 1;
       else
         return mid;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Take a pen and a paper. Start with a small size array, may be an array with `5` elements.  Dry run the loop body logic. You can also add the `printf` statements in the loop body which will print the value of variables in every iteration. This way you can build your skill of understanding the code flow and logic implemented.

Comment: ever use a phone book? How about a dictionary?  Looking for a word that starts with 'p'? open it in the middle. If the words are before 'p', grab the pages to the right, split them in the middle and check again. Keep going until you get to p. That's a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I hope you are aware that binary search is used for sorted arrays. Elements should be in increasing order from left to right.

Now, the way your program works is by dividing the array in half based on the if else statements. You have the element x which needs to be searched, and both the ends of the array(0 index and n-1 index), in the beginning.

Now, our goal is to return the index of the element we have to search. Suppose the given array is {1,3,5,7,9,11}. And we want to search for 3 which is at index 1.

So when the function runs, mid is calculated. 0+(6-1) / 2 = 2,ie, the element at index 2, which is 5, is then compared to x. Since x=3 is lower, we now know that the element we want to search for cannot be ahead of index 2, or element value 5(because array is sorted), so we only need to search before 5. So, we run the loop with new high value=mid-1.

Now, the endpoint will be before mid, since we do not need to search after 5. And that's why high=mid-1, so that we don't go ahead of the mid element.

Answer (score 0):

binary search: search value only in 0 ~ nums.length - 1, so left = 0, right = nums.length - 1. When left = right = mid, nums[mid] still need to compare with target, so while(left <= right). As for mid + 1, mid - 1, it is because mid is not included in the next search range.

```
int binarySearch(int[] nums, int target) {
    int left = 0; 
    int right = nums.length - 1; // note

    while(left <= right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if(nums[mid] == target)
            return mid; 
        else if (nums[mid] < target)
            left = mid + 1; // note
        else if (nums[mid] > target)
            right = mid - 1; // note
    }
    return -1;
}
```

left_bound: seach target in 0 ~ nums.length, cause nums.length should be returned when target is larger than every element in nums. right = mid cause mid should be included in the next search range. left = mid + 1 cause mid shouldn't be included in the next search range. from right = mid, we can get that nums[right] >= target. So when left == right, just get the output.

```
int left_bound(int[] nums, int target) {
    if (nums.length == 0) return -1;
    int left = 0;
    int right = nums.length; // note
    
    while (left < right) { // note
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (nums[mid] == target) {
            right = mid;
        } else if (nums[mid] < target) {
            left = mid + 1;
        } else if (nums[mid] > target) {
            right = mid; // note
        }
    }
    return left;
}
```

right_bound: seach target in 0 ~ nums.length, cause nums.length should be returned when target is no less than every element in nums. right = mid cause mid should be included in the next search range. left = mid + 1 cause mid shouldn't be included in the next search range. from right = mid, we can get that nums[right] >= target. So when left == right, just get the output.

```
int right_bound(int[] nums, int target) {
    if (nums.length == 0) return -1;
    int left = 0, right = nums.length;
    
    while (left < right) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (nums[mid] == target) {
            left = mid + 1; // note
        } else if (nums[mid] < target) {
            left = mid + 1;
        } else if (nums[mid] > target) {
            right = mid;
        }
    }
    return left; // note
}
```